# Why won't my Soligor lens work on my Nikon D5000?

Tags: lens

I have a Nikon D5000 and got a Soligor 55-200 lens. It seems to go on but the screen says `Lens Not Attached`. Why?

Answer (score 3):

This is a non-CPU lens, i.e. it doesn't have an electrical connection to the camera, hence the camera can't possibly "know" that there is a lens attached at all.

You are probably in an auto mode. Switch to M, set the aperture using the ring on the lens, then set the shutter speed using the dial on the camera. It should work this way.